# Finding a table based on foreign key

Tags: c#, ef-core-2.2

I have these two tables and the bridge between them:

```
public class User
    {
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserLocation> UserLocations { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class Location
    {
        [Required]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Picture { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public ICollection<UserLocation> UserLocations { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class UserLocation
    {
        public Location Location { get; set; }
        public int LocationId { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
    }
```

I need to create a method that takes as a parameter a search field and a user id, returns all locations realted to that user id and searches if the string is contained in any of the locations' props.

I am having issues returning the locations based on user id.

I tried `_context.UserLocations.Include(ul=>ul.Location).Where(l=>l.UserId==userId)`
but that didn't work since I got a syntax error when trying to use `l.UserId`.
I also tried the other way around, `_context.Locations.Include(l=>l.UserLocations)` but ran into the same issue.

I need to find a way to retrieve all locations related to the user. The search can be easily done using the `Contains()` method afterwards.

Comment: Try this: _context.UserLocations.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).select(x => x.Location)

Comment: What's in your OnModelCreation? Did you properly specify your relationships? Or you should try ForeignKey attribute also. Might solve your problem

Comment: @A.Jo yes, that's exactly what I needed! :D If you'd like, you can answer and I'll accept it asap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
_context.UserLocations.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).Select(x => x.Location)
```